# I will report to you "in" or "at" Blacktown Hospital?

Tags: prepositions

I am confused about this sentence.

Which statement is correct?

I will report to you in Blacktown Hospital, at 8:00 AM.

I will report to you at Blacktown Hospital, at 8:00 AM.

Comment: 'comma' seems superfluous. Well, to answer, use 'at' if you are concerned about the 'place' i.e. a physical building.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the difference between "in" and "at" concerning hospital is that by using "in" you mean that you are a patient of that hospital. If you use "at", you show that at the moment you are in the hospital building (like if you are a doctor or came there for some business).

Comment: Or the other guy is a patient.  But if the author is "reporting" by showing up for work, probably neither of them is a patient. So I agree "at" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

For context, "I will report to you" conveys that you are subordinate to the person you are meeting.

"at" is the more usual usage.

"in" emphasises that the meeting will take place *inside the hospital building*, and suggests that you will already be in the building, perhaps even that the person you are meeting will be arriving shortly before the meeting and will locate themselves in an office there.

"at" means the meeting will take place in, or near (eg out front of) the hospital, and conveys a sense that you will arrive at the hospital in order to have the meeting - ie that it is not where you would normally be.